# Bash-How to move and rename a file in the order of oldest to newest

Tags: bash, shell-script, rhel

So I have a script I am trying to write.  It takes all .mp3 files from a directory and moves them to another directory and names them in numerical order, like 0001.mp3, 0002.mp3, ect.

```
i=0
for f in *.mp3; do
i=$((i+1));
mv "$f" "/home/jwt13/Testing/$(printf %04d $i).mp3";
done
```

Now I am trying to have it so the above command does the move and rename based on how old to file is.  So it will take the oldest file and name it 0001, the second oldest would be 0002.  How can I go about doing that using the above script?  Would I be able to add lines into this or would I need to re-write the entire thing a different way?

Thank you

Comment: do you have zsh available? It's available on RHEL, but not always installed by default.

Comment: I do not.  I thought zsh was a little different from bash?

Comment: zsh *is* a little different from bash; it has more powerful rename capabilities as well as wildcard expansion features that could innately sort the filenames by modification time. Bash has neither of those, which is why I asked :)

Answer (score 2):

You can just change `*.mp3` into `$(ls -rt *.mp3)`:

```bsh
i=0
for f in $(ls -rt *.mp3); do
    i=$((i+1));
    mv "$f" "/home/jwt13/Testing/$(printf %04d $i).mp3";
done
```

`-t` sorts files by modification time, and `-r` makes the oldest file come first.

As mentioned by @Jeff, the above doesn't work when filenames contain weird characters. In that case, you should use this(still can't handle newline characters):

```bsh
i=0
ls -rt *.mp3 |
while read -r f; do
    i=$((i+1));
    mv "$f" "/home/jwt13/Testing/$(printf %04d $i).mp3";
done
```

where output of `ls` is piped into the whole `while` loop.

Comment: unless any of those filenames have space, tab, newline, or wildcard characters in them...

Comment: Oh god I cant believe it was that simple.  I was thinking I would need an entire new line of commands.  Thanks so much for the quick response.

Comment: Wound the find command handle newline characters?

Comment: @thango `-print0` and `-exec` options can, but `find` can’t sort files by time.